# Android Push Notification using firebase from ruby on rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, push-notification

How to send push notification to Android Mobile using firebase from ruby on rails. I know rails-push-notifications and others but I want using firebase so kindly provide documentation for how to send push notification using firebase in android application.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me...

Add this `gem 'fcm'` into your gemfile, run the command `bundle install`.

Create a method and paste this:

```
require 'fcm'

fcm = FCM.new(server_key) # Find server_key on: your firebase console on web > tab general > web api key

registration_ids= [device_keys] # Array of keys generated by firebase for devices 

options = {
        priority: "high",
        collapse_key: "updated_score", 
        notification: {
            title: "Message Title", 
            body: "Hi, Worked perfectly",
            icon: "myicon"}
        }

response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
```

[more about gem fcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm)

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this [fcm gem](https://github.com/spacialdb/fcm) that allows you to send notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

```
require 'fcm'

fcm = FCM.new("my_api_key")
# you can set option parameters in here
#  - all options are pass to HTTParty method arguments
#  - ref: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L29-L60
#  fcm = FCM.new("my_api_key", timeout: 3)

registration_ids= ["12", "13"] # an array of one or more client registration tokens
options = {data: {score: "123"}, collapse_key: "updated_score"}
response = fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
```

YM

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to use Gem, it does not work for my application. but I'm using React to use POST Method (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) with the following header contents:

```
{
    server_key: web_api_key_on_console_web
},

body: {
    to: Mobile_token_created_by_phone,
    notification: {
        title: "Judul",
        body: "Isi pesan"
    },
}
```